Replace value with first non-null from different column
How to replace a value at row (in col V2) with the first non-null in another column (V1) over a group? Using when/then with is_not_null().first() replaces the whole column.
fr = pl.DataFrame({'Cat': ['A']*4 + ['B']*4, 'V1': [None, 1, 2, None]*2, 'V2': [None, None, None, 555]*2})

shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Cat ┆ V1   ┆ V2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ A   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘

Desired result:
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Cat ┆ V1   ┆ V2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ A   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ A   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ B   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘


What you describe doesn't match your desired result. For example for Cat=A, V1=2, according to what you've described, V2 should be 1 because that's the first not null in column V1. It seems you only want to do that when that value = V1. Do I have that last part right?

Sorry if it's unclear. I'm looking for the location of first non-null in V1 and use that value in V2 (over 'Cat').

You could use a boolean mask with is_not_null and cum_sum over Cat, and when:
fr.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('V1').is_not_null() &   
                        pl.col('V1').is_not_null().cum_sum()
                          .over(pl.col('Cat'))==1)
                  .then(pl.col('V1'))
                  .otherwise(pl.col('V2')).alias('V2')
               )

Variant with is_first_distinct suggested by @Hericks, combined with over:
fr.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('V1').is_not_null() &
                        pl.col('V1').is_not_null().is_first_distinct()
                          .over(pl.col('Cat')))
                  .then(pl.col('V1'))
                  .otherwise(pl.col('V2')).alias('V2')
               )

Output:
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Cat ┆ V1   ┆ V2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ A   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ A   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ A   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ B   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ B   ┆ null ┆ 555  │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘


pl.col('V1').is_not_null().cum_sum() can be 1 for multiple values within each group. You could use pl.col("V1").is_not_null() & pl.col("V1").is_not_null().is_first_distinct() instead.

@Hericks yes that's true I also thought of that. I'll edit.
